# Magneto 2: referencecontainer and container

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to know the difference between `<container>` and `<referenceContainer>` for layout file.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Container:**
A structure without content that holds other layout elements such as blocks and containers.

**referenceBlock and referenceContainer:**
Updates in `<referenceBlock>` and `<referenceContainer>` are applied to the corresponding `<block>` or `<container>`.

For example, if you make a reference by `<referenceBlock name="right">`, you are targeting the block `<block name="right">`.

To pass parameters to a block use the `<argument></argument>` instruction.

[Magento Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#:%7E:text=A%20structure%20without%20content%20that%20holds%20other%20layout%20elements%20such%20as%20blocks%20and%20containers.)

Comment: so that means the referenceContainer/referenceBlock are used to make changes in Container/ Block. the name is mentioned in the name attribute of referenceContainer/referenceBlock? right?

Answer (score 0):

**Container**

A structure without content that holds other layout elements such as blocks and containers.

A container renders child elements during view output generation. It can be empty or it can contain an arbitrary set of `<container>` and `<block>` elements.

**referenceContaine**

Updates in `<referenceContainer>` are applied to the corresponding  `<container>`.

In otherwork we can said that, if you want make any changes into the particular `Container` at that time you can use there refrence.